# How do I get results from Matlab in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, interop

I can call a `.m` file in Matlab from Java and that works fine, but I want to retrieve the results from Matlab and display them in Java. How can I do this?

Comment: @Asmaa: I think I got the essence of your question, but it was a difficult read. If I glossed over something important, add it in and I'll try to clear it up.

Comment: Sorry... (Hey, why am I apologizing for being helpful?)

Comment: @Welbog: There, I think I picked up the highlights from your edit.

Comment: @mmyers: Because these are the edit wars! No helpful edit goes uncriticized!

Comment: Can you provide more details about where you're having difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

[matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com) is a Java API which will allow you to do just that. It allows for invoking eval and feval in MATLAB and returning the results to MATLAB. The [walkthrough](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough) explains with examples how to do this. The walkthrough uses built-in MATLAB functions and commands, but you can use it with your own .m files because using matlabcontrol is just like interacting with MATLAB's Command Window.